# Entity framework table relationship not showing

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following tables:

## Users

ItemID(int), identity --Primary Key
UserID varchar(25) --Unique Index

## UserItems

ItemID(int), identity --Primary key
UserID varchar(25)
UserItems varchar(100)

There is a relationship between users.userID and userItems.userid , however when loading the Model it doesn't display the relaionship.

Any reasons why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that: 
Inheritance Support with Unique Constraints – Support mapping inheritance based on unique constraints as opposed to primary key ,are not supported by EF4.

References:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/03/09/unique-constraints-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

thanks